# Looking for sci fi novel about autonomous cars that take over from people. Early to mid 1960's

Tags: story-identification, robots

Mankind has mass produced very ostentatious autonomous cars that serve us. Cars rebel and make people serve them. New cars made are square white boxes.  It was a spot on satire of mankind's lust for big chrome cars but the AI piece was prescient too. Written no later then 1967.

Comment: And it's a whole novel, not a short story?

Comment: might be a novella...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Four Day Weekend](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OT69IE)* by George Henry Smith, published in 1966.

[image]

From the back cover:

> THE REVOLT OF THE MACHINES
>
> It was impossible, of course, because the machines had been ruling
>   everything for 100 years, so what could they revolt against?
>
> They decided people had outlived their usefulness to them, and that
>   genocide of 4 billion people on Planet Earth was the best policy.
>
> And into this incredible situation Charles Henry Hyde was thrust, with
>   a shrew of a wife named Agnes who nagged like it was 1966...

At the beginning of the last chapter, the protagonists encounter plain white cars.

> The cars waiting for them were unlike any Chuck had ever seen. They
>   were completely white, even to the tread on the tires and they had no
>   chrome on them anywhere.
>
> "These must be the new generation," he said. "The ones they designed
>   to please themselves."

Spoiler. It turns out that...

> Aliens had reprogrammed the "Omnivac" that was controlling the cars,
>  so the AI element was a red herring.

Comment: I recall a more recent version of this, 70s or early 80s? From a well-known author.Aliens arrive and start making perfect flying cars, then houses.... and then the serialization ended.

Comment: Yes!  You got it...  The Four Day Weekend was a hoot when I read it as a kid.  Curious to see how it has aged...

Comment: Thanks!! Will track it down and re-read it.

Comment: Thanks! I loved it as a kid.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the children's novel [The Endless Pavement](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL5415351M/The_endless_pavement) by Jacqueline Jackson?

The story revolves around cars taking over the planet and making it an 'endless pavement."

> Living in a time when ***people are the servants of automobiles*** and ruled by the master auto of the planet, Josette longs to leave her rollabout and try her legs.

The timing is a bit later than what you noted.  I.e. 1973.  But, it does talk about white vehicles. Or, more accurately red & white:

> In a red-and-white striped Home-a-rolla